# Physical Quantities

Tags: homework-and-exercises, units

What are the physical quantities which most relate to their definition? Could you give some examples?

The definition I found is: " it is any property which can be measured".

In the case of mass the given example is "when we go buy apples we purchase two kilograms of apples.

Please give another example.

Comment: I've no idea what your precise question is. Are you just asking for examples of units?

Answer (score 1):

Read the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Units_of_measurement), it has something about conversion of units.

If you have a length, you can express it as

- 1 foot (ft)
- 32 centimeter (cm)
- 320 millimeter (mm)
- 0.32 meter (m)
- 12 inch (in)

The numbers are different, but the units are also. *Together*, they represent the same length in reality.

The SI base units are defined in various ways, see [the origins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_the_metric_system).